# Tell Autotest to run every time I changed models/controllers/helpers in Rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rspec2, autotest

I would like to tell autotest to run every time I changed models/controllers/helpers in my rails 3. Currently, it runs only when I changed spec files.

Here is my environments:

- rails (3.0.3)
- rspec-rails (2.4.1)
- autotest (4.4.6)
- autotest-notification (2.3.1)
- Ubuntu 10.10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've just found solution, I have to install autotest-rails-pure and add both autotest and autotest-rails-pure into Gemfile.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to modify some settings for autotest. The rspec repo has a good wiki page on integration with autotest.

https://github.com/dchelimsky/rspec/wiki/Autotest-Integration